# Some advices about a project semi-structured data

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I'm stydying to get an advanced degree in computer science and I have a course about completions of databases in which we study semi-structured data (xml) and how to work on them and information retrieval. The exam is to build a little project. Since I am very interested in the first part I'd like to code a mini program where I can work with sql/xml, flowr expressions, xquery and conversion from sql to xml and viceversa. It would be good for me to propose a project from my own because should I let the professor decide for me, I'm sure he would give me a too complex project. Have you got any nice or useful idea to give me to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system), a blog engine, and allow the people store the information in XML files (that is good for hosting without MySQL database) , or in MySQL (as most of the CMS, like WordPress); and you can write some functions to import/export from MySQL to XML and vice versa.

Those are my two cents :)

Comment: Nice idea! Maybe people could write some posts which are firstly saved as xml and then enclosed in a sql table? Or maybe, when a search needs to be performed xml data could be extracted from the table and then perform an xquery on tags...

Comment: You have infinite possibilities!
For example, you can use the MySQL database as "backup" for the XML files.
Or you can "duplicate" the logic of your program, in XML and MySQL. I mean, if the user gives you a MySQL database, you use the database to store the information, if not, you store the posts in XML files.
Or you can design an interface, and allow the user choose if he wants to use the MySQL database or the XML system.
Good luck with the project!